# Book indexing data science project

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, books, indexing, data-indexing-techniques

Is it possible to perform Book index searching using Machine learning algorithms?

Inputs :

1 Book pages with page numbers as images.

2 Index words in the book.

Output: Tracing the page number/s with the indexes provided.